# Best practice for outlier removal in Investigating a process deviation

Tags: outliers

In a controlled process, in which a specific product depicted a deviation in a final product result. The process is time controlled, in which the historical manufacturing experience of the product is well established. If product X final result deviated from the process, and upon discovering it an investigation was launched. Assuming that the product traveled from site A to B historically between 2-5 hours. Using a dataset of manufacturing experience btw 2014 to 2018, and excluding the product being investigated, should I remove the outliers as they are not a representative of the process?, the underline objective is to understand why this product final result deviated from the normal process by observing the dataset using 3SD and see where product X falls, with outliers the dataset is not normally distributed(Note: Time would affect the result, hence it is controlled)

Answer (score 0):

**Comments:** I'm not sure I understand everything in your questions, most especially the connection between the data and your product and the ultimate purpose of your analysis. But maybe a start is to address some of the misconceptions.

"Should I remove the outliers as they are not representative of the process?"
In general, **No.** How do you know the outliers are not an inherent part of the distribution of the process?

Consider the following 50 observations (sorted in order):

```
x
 [1] 0.01 0.01 0.03 0.05 0.06 0.06 0.13 0.15 0.17 0.19 0.23 0.26 0.28 0.30 0.35
[16] 0.38 0.39 0.42 0.42 0.43 0.46 0.50 0.50 0.51 0.53 0.66 0.70 0.75 0.76 0.90
[31] 0.91 0.95 1.03 1.12 1.19 1.20 1.48 1.56 1.59 1.71 2.13 2.22 2.38 2.59 2.59
[46] 2.95 3.04 3.11 3.76 3.89

pm = -1:1;  mean(x) + pm*3*sd(x)
##  -2.104872  1.039800  4.184472
```

So values in $\bar X \pm 3S$ lie in the interval $[-2.11,4.19].$ According to
that criterion, there are no outliers. But the $3$SD criterion is not
the only or (arguably) even the best criterion. A boxplot of the data shows
two outliers:

[image]

I can remove them, but then different high values will seem to be outliers. Looking at a stripchart of these values, which values would you remove as outliers?

[image]

Extreme "surgery" might be to get rid of anything above $1.$ Then what's left
of the data "passes" a normality test; according to the flimsy criterion that the null hypothesis
of normality is not rejected at the 5% level of significance.

```
shapiro.test(x[x < 1])

        Shapiro-Wilk normality test

data:  x[x < 1]
W = 0.94443, p-value = 0.1
```

Is this severely truncated partial dataset now "representative of the process"?
Many waiting time processes are exponential, and the original fifty observations
are from an exponential population, not a normal one.

Outliers of the kind seen
from the start are *typical* of an exponential distribution. And the result
of trimming away everything above 1 does *not really* result in a normal sample. It merely results in a sample that's too small to distinguish from normal.
The result is a truncated exponential sample, not a normal one.

So for many datasets occurring in practice, the idea of looking for "failures" by assuming data must be normal or that all outliers in a sample are unrepresentative of the process that produced them is not necessarily a good idea.
(Even data from a normal distribution often show a few boxplot outliers; over a third of normal samples of size fifty do.)

So before we can be helpful, you need to explain your problem, assumptions, and objectives more carefully.